# Error: 'Mesh' object has no attribute 'use_auto_smooth' when importing .zmbx (Metabricks) file into Blender

Tags: python, animation, blender, mesh

I was trying to make a Lego animation. As the title suggests, I tried to import a mesh that I had downloaded as a .zmbx file from a website called mecabricks.com, but this error comes up when I try to import it. [image: error]

It shows up on the workbench, but is completely invisible, and I doubt the mesh has loaded. I have Mecabricks lite installed (https://mecabricks.com/en/shop/product/2) and Epic fig rig (https://github.com/BlenderBricks/EpicFigRig). Both were successfully loaded into blender, and I have no idea what the error could be. (I am following this tutorial, if this helps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_R3wSmdmM8). I am using Blender 4.1 on Windows.